# Laravel display validation error

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation

I try use this code:

```
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{!!   $error !!}</li>
                @endforeach
```

and in view have this:
[image: screen]

I would like the error to be displayed correctly.
exemple **The name is required.**

In debbuger I can see.
How to replace validation.required upon "The name is required"
[image]

Comment: Have you returned the errors in the controller with an validator?

Comment: I make new request and I wrote in controller -> return redirect('route');

Comment: see the answers below with $request->validate method

Comment: If you return after the submission, ofcourse Laravel loses the data. What did you expect? If you realy want to redirect, do it [with flashed session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data).

Comment: Ok, I know. An error from the validator is displayed to me in a view only in a strange form such as "validation.reqiured". See screen above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found mistake. I didn't have another language to upload.
In file app/config.php replace  'locale' => 'pl' to 'en'

Answer (score 8):

you need to add validation in controller method like this..

```
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);
```

then you can show your validation error in view :

```
   @if ($errors->has('name'))
      <li>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</li>
   @endif
```

and this should also work ...

```
 <ul>
     @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
         <li>{{ $error }}</li>
     @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: @Ankit Why do we need to chain  `all()`? If `$errors` is an array we can simply loop using foreach.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari `$errors` is not an array here, `$errors` is an object which consist all the validation errors, you can check, get and display the errors through the methods which errors class provide.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good example of handling errors in laravel

message.blade.php

```
@if($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p><strong>Opps Something went wrong</strong></p>
        <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">{{session('success')}}</div>
@endif

@if(session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{session('error')}}</div>
@endif
```

In your controller update method for instance,

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=>'required',
            'body'=>'required'
        ]);
       //the above validation is important to get the errors caught 
        $post= Post::find($id);
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');

        $post->save();

        return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Updated successfully');
    }
```

if you have a layout file as layout.blade.php NOTE: having the error display in the layout file is advantageous to use the message for all purpose.

```
...
<div class="container">
    @include('message')
    @yield('content')
</div>
...
```

Comment: This is not how you should [validate form submission](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests).

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
     <li>{{ $error }}</li>
 @endforeach
```